# mouse right click paste allow only numbers in all browser

Tags: jquery

I have input box jsfiddle link having a sample code i did
      https://jsfiddle.net/4rsv960t/173/
    I want to allow paste event with only numbers if its not a number then automatically empty the text box.

allow number only my sample code

```
$(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {
      console.log('allownumericwithoutdecimal called');
      $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
        if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
     });

 <input type="text" value="" class="allownumericwithoutdecimal"/>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly - Change your input to `<input type="number" value="" class="allownumericwithoutdecimal"/>` and it will remove the non numbers automatically for you when pasting, no javascript needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as

```js
$(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("input", function(event) {
  this.value = /^\d+$/.test(this.value) ? this.value : "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" class="allownumericwithoutdecimal" />
```

Or keep the numbers

```js
$(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("input", function(event) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" class="allownumericwithoutdecimal" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly (not sure what this means `if its not a number then automatically empty the text box`)

You don't need javascript for this.

If you change your input type to `number`, when pasting, non numbers will be removed automatically

```html
<input type="number" value="" class="allownumericwithoutdecimal" /><br /> 123456asd456asd
<p>Copy the above and paste into input</p>
```